# Import Automation error

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio

I have an import activity. When I run manually it works fine and add records to data extension from SFDC report.

When I run through an automation it throws an error.

Looks like a security issue but not sure.

Comment: can you provide more information on the error and the process you use to import this?

Comment: There's no difference between running an Import Activity manually from Interactions and running it through an Automation. Is your "manual" step different than running it from the Interactions tab?

Comment: I have created import activity, which import salesforce report. If I run that activity by selecting manually it works fine. But if I run through automation studio it returns error. I am using automation studio for other import activities as well only one of these giving error where manually it works fine.